# Can we ask 'What something does' (through a picture, or perhaps through a video link)?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, closed-questions

I started writing a question on the main site but then realised that it may be considered off topic. As I hovered over the menu for the Aviation S.E group I noticed it said "`...for pilots, mechanics and enthusiasts`" so I am posting (not the question) on here first, for clarification.

Being an enthusiast who has recently just started working towards a PPL; questions come in quick succession. I feel it is important to establish this answer.

**Can we ask what 'something' does? Either via a Cockpit Picture or a video link perhaps?** By something, I mean an instrument, perhaps an article in a PDF which explains procedures, or certain terms specific to aviation? Of course, the question must **not** be lazy, one should have at least attempted to answer the question as **best** as possible.

The reason I ask is that I am a member of a few Exchange groups, take Music Theory and Practice for example. It is (for some reason) forbidden to ask "What is the instrument here..." when someone would be able to inform me, but as I say, it is forbidden.

Answer (score 5):

We get those kind of questions often. Just [one example](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/24799/8730). They're usually well received as long as it's not something a simple Google search can answer.

Comment: And, btw, the "what is the instrument here" questions seem to be perfectly fine on Music Fans.se

Answer (score 0):

When asking about a video, be sure to take a screenshot of the relevant frame(s). Because it's not uncommon for videos to be removed, such examples are:

- [Can a helicopter carry a large airplane?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/34300/14897)
- [Why would a RAT be deployed at takeoff?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/35121/14897) (frame was added before video was removed)