# Can we ask questions about identifying a video corresponding to airline industry?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

Can we post a links to videos here and ask to identify a particular event, for example an air crash disaster?

I run into a short cameo of a total destruction of a plane being part of Queen's Innuendo official video:

https://youtu.be/eKClwkbDO1o?t=131

And I wanted to ask, if anyone is able to identify this particular air crash (or otherwise "source" of this cameo). But I have some doubts that such question will be off-topic here.

Comment: Related: [Can we ask 'What something does' (through a picture, or perhaps through a video link)?](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3491/14897) -- be sure to include a frame (screenshot), as some videos get removed off YouTube or are geo-blocked.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the necessity of adding screenshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd be willing to entertain it being on topic, along the same lines as aircraft identification.

This one happens to be a [DC-7 crash test](https://aviation-safety.net/database/record.php?id=19640424-1) in 1964. [Here's the section of video they used.](https://youtu.be/4D3dmy5bE7M?t=22)

Comment: Coulda waiting for the question itself to answer it ;)

Comment: Done! :> https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/75608/3230 Thx!